# Set Reverse Zoom Direction

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am practicing the use of forge and starting with the viewfinder. I am currently using Forge version 6 ... I would like to set the zoom address. I found a methodist who receives a bool called setReverseZoomDirection. But I can't find information on how to use it.

I have intended to use it as follows in the onItemLoadSuccess (viewer, item) method but I have not succeeded

```
onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
      console.log("onItemLoadSuccess()!");
      viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.setTheme("light-theme");
      console.log(viewer)

      viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.navigation.SetReverseZoomDirection(true);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method name should be `setReverseZoomDirection` w/o the starting `s` in small letter:

```
NOP_VIEWER.navigation.setReverseZoomDirection(true/false)
```

If still no luck try postpone setting the direction until the model is loaded - say when the `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` is fired:

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,()=>{
   //...
})
```

PS: `ViewerApplication` has been deprecated as of v7+ so consider migrating to v7 - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/) for details.